# CakePHP multilevel models

Tags: cakephp, model, associations, multi-level

I've been trying to figure out how to save multi-level models in CakePHP for some time now, but can't seem to find a solution.

I have three models. **Survey**, **Question**, and **Choice**.

- **Survey** hasMany **Question** - *so **Question** belongsTo **Survey***
- **Question** hasMany **Choice** - *so **Choice** belongsTo **Question***

  - The **Question** is linked to the **Survey** through its **survey_id** key.
  - The **Choice**, on the otherhand, is linked to the **Question** through its **question_id** key. (not directly linked to **Survey** though)

The form is created through `$this->Form->create('Survey')`.

I want the application to save a survey with its corresponding questions, **AND** each question having their corresponding choice(s).

The problem is, only the **Survey** and **Question** models are saved. **Choice** gets discarded.

I'm using `$this->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array( 'deep' => true) )`

I will be updating my post to show the `$_POST` data.

Thanks,

XTN

Comment: What version of Cake are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before saving data, you have to ensure that data should be in this format

in your controller:

```
$data = array('Survey' => array('id' => 1,'name' => 'test'),
                  'Question' => array(
                                    array('id' => 1,'question' => 'test1','survey_id' => 1,
                                        'Choice' => array(
                                            array('id' => 1,'question_id' => 1,'choice' => 1),
                                            array('id' => 2,'question_id' => 1,'choice' => 2)
                                            )

                                    ),
                                    array('id' => 2,'question' => 'question2','survey_id' => 1,
                                    'Choice' => array(
                                        array('id' => 3,'question_id' => 2,'choice' => 'sd'),
                                        array('id' => 4,'question_id' => 2,'choice' => 'we')
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                 );
        $this->Survey->create();
        $this->Survey->saveAssociated($data,array('deep'=>true));
```

Survey Model :

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Question' => array(
        'className' => 'Question',
        'foreignKey' => 'survey_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    )
         );
```

Question Model :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Survey' => array(
        'className' => 'Survey',
        'foreignKey' => 'survey_id',
    )
);
public $hasMany = array(
    'Choice' => array(
        'className' => 'Choice',
        'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    )
);
```

Choice Model :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Question' => array(
        'className' => 'Question',
        'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
    )
);
```

I think it will work if found any problem please notify

Answer (score 0):

Your models should looks like:

`Survey Model: Survey.php`

```
class Survey extends AppModel {   
    public  $name = 'Survey';   
    public $hasMany = array('Questions' => array(
                                          'className' => 'Question',
                                          'foreignKey' => 'survey_id'
                                                )
                           );
}
```

`Question Model: Question.php`

```
class Question extends AppModel{   
public $name = 'Question';   
public $belongsTo = array(
                        'Survey' => array('className' => 'Survey', 'foreignKey' => 'survey_id'),
                        'Answer' => array('className' => 'Choice', 'foreignKey' => 'answer_id'));
public $hasMany = array('Choices' => array('className' =>  'Choice', 
                                           'foreignKey' => 'question_id'));
}
```

`Choice Model: Choice.php`

```
class Choice extends AppModel
{
public $name = 'Choice';   
public $belongsTo = array('Question' => array('className' => 'Question', 
                                              'foreignKey' => 'question_id'));   
}
```

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.